# counting the number of brackets using array

Tags: c

I am new to coding and would really appreciate if you could help me with this question. I can't find out why my code does not give me the correct result. Thank you for your time!!

Q:
Using a first dimensional array, count the number of closing brackets and open brackets. Input must be in one line. 
Ex. Input: (()))
    Output: 3 2

I used an array to receive the input in one line and the for loop to count the number of opening/closing brackets.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
char str[1000]; int l=0;r=0;

printf("Enter:\t");
gets(str);

int length=sizeof(str)/sizeof(str[0]);

for(int i=0;i!=EOF && i<length;i++)
{
    if(str[i]=='(')
    l++;
    else if(str[i]==')')
    r++;
}
printf("%d %d",l,r);
}
```

Expected
Input: (())
Output: 2 2

What I get
Input: (())
Output: 6 2

Comment: `i!=EOF`  meaning? Also, `int length=sizeof(str)/sizeof(str[0]);` is not length of string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your loop is wrong (actually your conditions)

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < strlen(str);i++)
{
    if(str[i]=='(')
    {
        l++;
    }
    if(str[i]==')')
    {
        r++;
    }
}
```

Comment: What problem do you have with my answer?

Answer (score 1):

`i!=EOF` is not needed as this is not a file

`int length=sizeof(str)/sizeof(str[0])` doesnt give the length of the string `strlen()`  from  `#include <string.h>` does

Answer (score 0):

There are mistakes which are covered in basic C learning.

`sizeof(str)/sizeof(str[0]);` returns size of `str` array which is in your case `1000`. To get length of user input, use `strlen` function: `int length = strlen(str)`.

Later, use your `for` loop as `for(int i=0;i<length;i++)` or better:

```
//Include string.h on beginning of file
#include <string.h>

size_t length = strlen(str);
for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    //Do your if.
}
```

Comment: What would be the default value for an uninitialized element in a string?
If my input is ab() for char string[5], then string[0]=a, string[1]=b, string[2]=(, string[3]=). What would be the value for string[4]? Is it 0 just like in an array? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You also have a syntax error at the declaration of r.
You would either have int l=0,r=0;
Or 
Int l=0;
Int r=0;
Although, the compiler should have warned you about this.